# Copying data from a referenced workbook

Tags: excel, vba, reference, copy

I am getting a subscript out of range error on the first if statement.
I had this working when it was all within the same Workbook just different sheets
I want it to reference a different workbook to gets it data from.
I did the tools -> reference -> "Report" workbook that way I know it is open.

```
  Sub update_cell1_InProcess()
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    
     b = 31
    lRow = Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets("CopyDatabase").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
       If Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets("CopyDatabase").Cells(i, 5).Value = Workbooks("Big screen.xlsm").Sheets("CELL_1").Cells()(1, 2).Value Then   'B1
            If Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets("CopyDatabase").Cells(i, 1).Value = Workbooks("Big screen.xlsm").Sheets("CELL_1").Cells()(1, 1).Value Then  'A1
                If Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets("CopyDatabase").Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" Then 'not blank
                    If Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets("CopyDatabase").Cells(i, 8).Value = "" Then
                    
                         Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets("CopyDatabase").Rows(i).Copy

                        
                         Workbooks("Big screen.xlsm").Sheets("SHEET1").Activate
                       
                         Workbooks("Big screen.xlsm").Sheets("SHEET1").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        b = b + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
          End If
        
        Next
        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Just different If statements but code that worked in same workbook different sheets

```
Sub update_cell1_completed()

Dim lRow As Long

 b = 1
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lRow
   If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets("CELL_1").Cells()(1, 2).Value Then  'B1
        If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("CELL_1").Cells()(1, 1).Value Then  'A1
            If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" Then 'not blank
                If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 8).Value <> "" Then 'not blank
                
                    Worksheets("TEST").Rows(i).Copy
                    
                    
                   Worksheets("SHEET1").Activate
                   
                    Worksheets("SHEET1").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    b = b + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
      End If
    
    Next
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue, but I feel like `Cells()(1, 2).Value` should actually be `Cells(1, 2).Value` and same for the 1,1

Comment: Typically speaking, Subscript Out of Range means it couldn't find an object referenced in the code.  Are both workbooks open when you run this?  If not, you'll need to include a Workbooks.Open line so that the code opens the missing workbook

Comment: Yes it is open with the reference tool. It worked when it was in the same workbook separate sheets  it just is not working when I had it go to the other Workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code refactored to include proper object references and simply the multi-if statement.  See if you get the same error, and if so, let us know which line is erroring for you:

EDIT: Per comments, updated references to `Workbooks("Big screen.xlsm")` to instead be `ThisWorkbook`

```
Sub update_cell1_InProcess()
    
    Dim wbRprt As Workbook: Set wbRprt = Workbooks("Report.xlsm")
    Dim wbScrn As Workbook: Set wbScrn = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsDB As Worksheet:  Set wsDB = wbRprt.Worksheets("CopyDatabase")
    Dim wsC1 As Worksheet:  Set wsC1 = wbScrn.Worksheets("CELL_1")
    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet:  Set wsS1 = wbScrn.Worksheets("SHEET1")
    
    Dim lLastRow As Long:   lLastRow = wsDB.Cells(wsDB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lDestRow As Long:   lDestRow = 32
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lLastRow
        If wsDB.Cells(i, "E").Value = wsC1.Range("B1").Value _
        And wsDB.Cells(i, "A").Value = wsC1.Range("A1").Value _
        And Len(wsDB.Cells(i, "F").Value) > 0 _
        And Len(wsDB.Cells(i, "H").Value) > 0 Then
            wsDB.Rows(i).Copy wsS1.Cells(lDestRow, "A")
            lDestRow = lDestRow + 1
        End If
    Next i
        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: With that code i am getting the subscript our of range on the Set wbScrn = Workbooks("Big screen.xlsm") Which is the workbook this is in

Comment: Alright, in that case are you 100% certain that "Big screen.xlsm" is the name of the workbook? It doesn't have a weird character for the space, any extra whitespaces, spelling is correct, etc?  That error says it can't find a workbook that's open exactly named "Big screen.xlsm"

Comment: If the code resides in the workbook named "Big screen.xlsm", can change all references from that to instead be `ThisWorkbook`, I'll edit the post so you can copy the code and try again

Comment: See updated answer for the edit

Comment: `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is redundant since you're not pasting. It would be better to write the criteria values from `A1` and `B1` to variables instead of reading them from the worksheet on each iteration.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I agree, but that's not what this question was about.  The code refactor was done only to help identify the source of the error in this question